# Coarse Moduli space of plane cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, moduli-space

I am studying Joe Harris' Algebraic Geometry: A First Course, the section
on Moduli Spaces, pg 278. I am stuck in a subtle point.
Harris gives on p 279 an argument why there is no *coarse* moduli space
of plane cubics and I not understand this argument:

> **Example 21.12.** Plane Cubics
> The fundamental example of a moduli space is one we
> encountered before in Example 10.16, that of plane cubics.
> Based on our previous discussion, we see that
> even a coarse moduli space does not exist for plane cubics.
> This is due to the various inclusions among closures of
> orbits of the action of $PGL_3 \ K$ ($K$ field with
> $char(K) \neq 2,3$)n on the space $\mathbb{P}^9$
> of plane cubics. For example, if $\mathcal{M}$ is the
> set of isomorphism classes of plane cubics, $\mathcal{M}$
> will have one point $p$ corresponding to irreducible plane
> cubics with a node, and another point $q$ corresponding
> to cuspidal cubics. But by what we saw in Example
> 10.16, the point $q$ would have to lie in the closure of
> the point $p$!

Explantions on terminology & references:

1. the coarse moduli space is informally introduced at
   pges 278/279 as: Let $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ a collection
   of certain varieties (e.g. like genus $g$ curves, etc.).
   Then a variety $\mathcal{M}$ is called a *coarse moduli space* with
   respect this collection $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ if

- as underlying set $\mathcal{M}$ is bijective to
  the set of isomorphism classes of $X_{\alpha}$.
- for any reduced family $\pi: \mathcal{V} \to B$
  (ie a flat surjection such that the general fiber
  is reduced) such that
  every fiber $\pi^{-1}(b) = X_b $ is a member of the
  collection $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ the canonical set-theoretic map

$$ \phi_{\pi}: B \to \mathcal{M} $$

given by sending each point $b \in B$ to the point of
$\mathcal{M}$ representing the isomorphism
class $[X_b]$ of the fiber $X_b$ over $b$ is a
*regular map*.

2. Above is also refered to **Example 10.16.** ( How $PGL_3 \ K$
   Acts on $\mathbb{P}^9$) (page 121). It states that
   for base field $K$ with $char(K) \neq 2,3$ there exist
   a natural action of $PGL_3 \ K$ on the space
   of cubic polynomials on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

The interesting result was that this action has
some interesting *closure relationships*
among diverse orbits under this action. For example
the orbit consisting of smooth cubics with $j$-invariant
$j$ contains in its closure
the locus of cuspidal cubics (i.e., the orbit of cubics
projectively equivalent to
$Y^2Z - X^3$).

This also implies that as stated above
that the closure of the orbit of point $p$ corresponding
to irreducible plane cubics with a node
contains point $q$ corresponding
to cuspidal cubic.

*Question*: Why this observation heuristically
indicates that if $q \in \overline{ \{p \} } \subset 
\mathcal{M}$ then $\mathcal{M}$ *cannot* be
a coarse moduli space of plane cubics? (and therefore a coarse moduli space of plane cubics not exist)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I have upvoted this stupid downvote. It happens sometimes on this site, without any reason in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that the $PGL_3 (K)$ action preserves isomorphism classes, but since $PGL$ is non-proper, the orbit closures contain limiting cases that are not of the same isomorphism class as the general fiber. So e.g. $y^2 = x^3 - tx$ is a family of nodal cubics over $\mathbb A^1$ with central fiber a cusp. Since all nodal cubics are abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ with $0$ and $\infty$ identified, the image of $\mathbb A^1$ induced by this family in $\mathcal M$ is a pair of isolated points ($0\mapsto [cusp]$ and $x \mapsto [node]$ for $x \in \mathbb A^1 \setminus 0$), showing that the map is not even continuous.

Comment: I think there is a subtle point here which should be clarified.
We consider the space $\mathcal{M}$ as a variety, therefore 
it is endowed with Zariski topology which is not Hausdorff. Therefore
we cannot separate arbitrary two points therefore and I'm not sure why it 
is immediately that
your map $f: \mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathcal{M}, 0 \mapsto [cusp],
x \neq 0 \mapsto [node]$ can't be continuous with resp underlying
topologies. Clearly in 
analytic topology where continuity can be defined by sequences
as $f: X \to Y$ is continuous

Comment: iff for every converging sequence 
$x_n \to x$ the image sequence converge as well $f(x_n) \to f(x)$
your map is discontinuous.

Comment: But here our topologies are coarser and we cannot separate
$p=[node]$ and $q=[cusp]$ since we observed above that
*if* $\mathcal{M}$ would be coarse moduli space then 
$q \in \overline{ \{p\} }$. Question: what are open 
sets in the image $f(\mathbb{A}^1)= \{ [node], [cusp] \} \subset \mathcal{M}$?
In order to show that $f$ is discontinuous we have to show that
$[cusp]$ is open in $f(\mathbb{A}^1)$, that is that there exist
open $U \subset \mathcal{M}$ which contains $[cusp]$ but not
$[node]$, but that's not obvious to me.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is continuous. We know from point-set topology that the continuous image of a connected set is connected. But since the nodal cubic and cuspidal cubic are each represented by closed points of $\mathcal M$, the set $\left\{[node],[cusp]\right\}$ is disconnected. Since $\mathbb A^1$ is connected, this is a contradiction.

Comment: If $\mathcal{M}$ would 
be our moduli space why $[node], [cusp]$ should be *closed* points of 
$\mathcal{M}$? That's exactly main reason for my confusion: a variety 
in general can of course have points (=primes) which are *not* closed. 
Why in this situation $[node], [cusp]$ you assume to be closed?

Comment: Has Harris actually introduced the notion of a non-closed point here? As is often the case with this book, the definition of course moduli space is somewhat vague. In particular, I *think* he wants you to think of $\mathcal M$ as a classical variety, so its closed points/$\mathbb C$-points are what is in bijection with isomorphism classes.

Comment: That seems to go indeed along with the philosophy of that book,
I accept your answer, because I think that Harris intended to point out
exactly that kind of problems, without dealing explicitely with distinction
between closed and nonclosed points.

Comment: My doubts previously making me not sure if *here* Harris regarded all points as closed,
stemmed from the fact that in the excerpt quoted above Harris 
wrote that *'the point $q$ would have to lie in the closure of the point $p$'*
and if in whole book all points of varieties are considered as closed, this
sentence is superfluous, since then the closure of a point is the point itself.

Comment: I think he's trying to point out that there is clearly something odd going on with the example (that it is isotrivial except at the central fiber) that suggests one point lying in the closure of another while still assuming all points are closed.